# Extract setting to top level val

Tags: sbt

Given:

```
resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val jar = (update in Compile).value
    .matching((_: ModuleID) == nemesisProto)
    .head
  IO.unzip(jar, (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "protobuf").toSeq
}.taskValue

PB.protoSources in Compile := Seq((resourceManaged in Compile).value / "protobuf")
```

**Is is possible to refactor `(resourceManaged in Compile).value / "protobuf"` to a common place?**

I tried assigning it to a val:

```
val protobufResourceFile = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "protobuf"

resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val jar = (update in Compile).value
    .matching((_: ModuleID) == nemesisProto)
    .head
  IO.unzip(jar, protobufResourceFile).toSeq
}.taskValue

PB.protoSources in Compile := Seq(protobufResourceFile)
```

Only to get the following error:

```
 error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.
val protobufResourceFolder = (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "protobuf"
                                                          ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. As the error message states you simply cannot unwrap a value outside the sbt dsl. So, something like this is usually done using a `SettingKey`:

```
val protobufResourceFile = settingKey[File]("Protobuf resource file ...")

protobufResourceFile := (resourceManaged in Compile).value / "protobuf"

resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
  val jar = (update in Compile).value
    .matching((_: ModuleID) == nemesisProto)
    .head
  IO.unzip(jar, protobufResourceFile.value).toSeq
}.taskValue

PB.protoSources in Compile := Seq(protobufResourceFile.value)
```

Though, in this specific case it may be overkill.